# position: sticky; not woking under Chrome mobile 79

Tags: css, position, sticky

I have made a sticky menu and it is not working under Chrome (mobile) 79
Under safari and desktop Chrome it is working perfect.
I use it in a DIV

```
<div style=divsticky>blabla </div>


.divsticky {
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            left: 0;
            display: table-cell;
            background-color:  #e2b577;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            padding: 3px, 10px;
            white-space:nowrap;
```

}

Comment: Add position: fixed

Comment: `style=divsticky` should be `class="divsticky"`

Comment: Note that `sticky` has some bugs when used by `table` elements and, presumably elements with that `display` type. - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Also `sticky` usually requires a `top` value...and you have other CSS errors in your code.

Comment: in inspector i get a yellow triangle on this: -webkit-sticky

Answer (score 1):

When i zoom totally out then it works.. So it have something to do with zooming.
This line make it work. But not when you zoom in...

When i place the entire index3.html into a iframe it works perfect.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>PLB_Admin</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <iframe width="99%" height="99%" frameborder="0" src="http://www.kraan.net/css/index3.html">
    </div>
</body>
```